# Asp.Net MVC and AngularJS in same View

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I´d like to know if exists a better way to render a view like this:
For the first load I need bring data from Controller like usual but after apply a filter in same page I need to start use AngularJS and never more uses Razor.
Is there a way to do that ?
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to implement ASP.Net MVC with AngularJs.

I personally like Mini SPA (Silos). You can watch Miguel A Castro's video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f67PFtrldGQ).

You can also download the source at his [website](http://www.melvicorp.com/downloads.html).

What it does is when a request comes in, it goes to ASP.Net MVC Route first. Then, Angular Route takes over the rest. It is a very slick design.

***FYI:*** I also use [Angular.Net Helpers](https://axelzarate.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/angular-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc/) to generate strongly typed views.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can do that.

Basically, you'd need to add the line below in your view. After you do that, the json is going to be available to the DOM / javascript and angular can take it from there. Hope this help

var json = '@Html.Raw(Model.MyJsonStringForMyCoolAngularJsApp)';

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebAPI project in visual studio to exchange data between frontend and backend.  It would go stateless, so to secure the data, you could use a mechanism like JWT.

The frontend would exchange JSONS from/to the backend using REST apis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can make angular views and exchange data using $http.get(/controller/method/). You can also configure routing using ngRoute.